# Using two bootstrap Carousels on one page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use two bootstrap Carousels on one webpage. The first one works fine, but the second doesnt work. Can I please have assistance to get the two to work?

I've tried changing the reference carousel but that doesnt work for some reason

I'm assuming they use the same js and css files?

The code can be run below

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
     interval:   4000
 });
 
 var clickEvent = false;
 $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
   clickEvent = true;
   $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
 }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  if(!clickEvent) {
   var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
   var current = $('.nav li.active');
   current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
   var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
   if(count == id) {
    $('.nav li').first().addClass('active'); 
   }
  }
  clickEvent = false;
 });
});
```

```css
body { padding-top: 20px; }
#myCarousel .nav a small {
    display:block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
    background:#eee;
}
#myCarousel .nav a {
    border-radius:0px;
}
header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: skyblue;
    
}
#header{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

header nav ul{
    text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
header nav ul li:last-of-type{
    margin-right: 0;
}

header nav ul li a{
        color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
 
         <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
                
      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
        

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>



<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
 
         <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
                
      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
        

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the second one?

Comment: @Ofisora Sorry forgot to mention i use the same one pasted twice in the html code

Comment: Can you please update the code?

Comment: @Ofisora done :P

Comment: you can only have one ID per page. give your second carousel a different ID. better yet, use a single class to call both of your carousels.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one `id` per page. Instead of giving your second carousel a different ID, give both of your carousels the same class and then reference that class in your javascript.

```
<div id="firstCarousel" class="carousel slide myCarousel">
<!-- rest of your code-->
</div><!--end carousel-->
<div id="secondCarousel" class="carousel slide myCarousel">
<!--rest of your code-->
</div><!--end carousel-->

//call all carousels with this class
$('.myCarousel').carousel();
```

This way, you won't have to repeat your Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

The carousel is referenced by its ID:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

So to use a second one, you need to give it a different ID, and provide the script to run the second instance:

```
<div id="mySecondCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


$(document).ready( function() {
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval:   4000
});

var clickEvent = false;
$('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
        clickEvent = true;
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    if(!clickEvent) {
        var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
        var current = $('.nav li.active');
        current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
        if(count == id) {
            $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
        }
    }
    clickEvent = false;
});

$('#mySecondCarousel').carousel({
    interval:   4000
});

var clickEventTwo = false;
$('#mySecondCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
        clickEventTwo = true;
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    if(! clickEventTwo) {
        var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
        var current = $('.nav li.active');
        current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
        if(count == id) {
            $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
        }
    }
    clickEventTwo = false;
});
});
```

And then modify the CSS to style both instances:

```
#myCarousel .nav a small,
#mySecondCarousel .nav a small {
    display:block;
}
#myCarousel .nav,
#mySecondCarousel .nav {
    background:#eee;
}
#myCarousel .nav a,
#mySecondCarousel .nav a {
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change our `id` name or use `class` if you want to use same name. I prefer using `class`, so there will be less code in `js` and `css`.

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/Sahero/pen/EvvNBj

Updated code:

**JS**: (Changed '#' to '.' to represent `class)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myCarousel").carousel({
    interval: 4000
  });

  var clickEvent = false;
  $(".myCarousel")
    .on("click", ".nav a", function() {
    clickEvent = true;
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  })
    .on("slid.bs.carousel", function(e) {
    if (!clickEvent) {
      var count = $(".nav").children().length - 1;
      var current = $(".nav li.active");
      current.removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
      var id = parseInt(current.data("slide-to"));
      if (count == id) {
        $(".nav li").first().addClass("active");
      }
    }
    clickEvent = false;
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.myCarousel .nav a small {
  display: block;
}
.myCarousel .nav {
  background: #eee;
}
.myCarousel .nav a {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
#header {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

header nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
header nav ul li:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="myCarousel carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

    </div>
    <!-- End Carousel Inner -->


    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
    </ul>

    <header class="row" id="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Logo</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Booking</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Price</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
  <!-- End Carousel -->
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

    </div>
    <!-- End Carousel Inner -->


    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

Don't forget to change the `data-target` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/a4ogrj3m/

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  var clickEvent = false;
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval:   4000
  }).on('click', '.nav a', function() {
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
  }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    if(!clickEvent) {
      var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
      var current = $('.nav li.active');
      current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
      if(count == id) {
        $('.nav li').first().addClass('active'); 
      }
    }
    clickEvent = false;
 });
});
```

```css
body { padding-top: 20px; }
#myCarousel .nav a small {
    display:block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
    background:#eee;
}
#myCarousel .nav a {
    border-radius:0px;
}
header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: skyblue;
    
}
#header{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

header nav ul{
    text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
header nav ul li:last-of-type{
    margin-right: 0;
}

header nav ul li a{
        color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
 
         <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
                
      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
        

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>



<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
 
         <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
        
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
                
      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
        

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

Your `ID` need to be **unique**, so change one the `carousel`'s `ID` & similarly change the target of `.nav a`.

I've used chaining method of `jQuery` & used the `.carousel` class to refer elements in `jQuery`.